# Date returned with Jdbc is in PDT timezone

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I have written a stand-alone script that stores dates (Date type field) in a mySQL database using Google Apps Script JDBC object. The timezone of the dates is UTC.

I do a query that selects all the dates, as an example:
SELECT `Date1` FROM `Table1`

When I retrieve the data using GetObject(1), it returns a Date object having PDT timezone set.
To be more precise, when I prompt theDate.toString(), it gives me:
Mon Jul 30 2012 23:51:25 GMT+0200 (CEST)
I notice that the original date (2012-07-30 14:51:25) from db has been considered as PDT and converted to GMT+2.

The Script timezone is not related and is set to GMT+1...

How can I tell to JDBC that the dates from the database are UTC?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that the script's time zone is set to PDT. Try to change the zone to GMT in Script Editor->File->Project Properties->Info Tab->Time Zone.

Comment: You mean `java.util.Date`? How do you tell it is PDT and not UTC?

Comment: No, not the Java's Date but your Google Apps Script's time zone. Open the GAS Editor and after click File->Project Properties->Info Tab->Time Zone and in the Time Zone combo select GMT.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentionned that in my first message. The Time Zone of the script is not related, currently it is set to French timezone GMT+1.

Comment: @ThierryChevillard: please answer Tomasz's question. How do you tell it is PDT? a java.util.Date doesn't have any timezone. It's only when you display the date that the date formatter/printer uses a timezone to display a date in a readable format.

Comment: @JBNizet, I edited my first post to answer Tomasz's question.

Comment: I am just dicovering new undocumented functions: JdbcResultSet.getDate(columnIndex, timeZone) that returns a JdbcDate object... I will give you a feedback but I think it will solve my problem.

Comment: JdbcResultSet.getDate(columnIndex, timeZone) takes timeZone into account, but JdbcResultSet.getTime(columnIndex, timeZone) and JdbcResultSet.getTimestamp(columnIndex, timeZone) do not. I reported what seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some debugging done in [Issue 1642](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1642) indicates that this is due to how JDBC works with MySQL, and the connection flags required to fix it currently can't be set in Apps Script.

To be clear through, the timezone shown when converting a JavaScript Date to a string will always be the timezone of the server, in this case Pacific Time. Use [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate) to display a Date in a specific timezone.