# Apps Script JDBC shifts timestamp to PDT time when saving to external MySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am writing a script is Apps Script environment that stores data to an external MySQL database with JDBC connector. Everything works fine except JDBC shifts timestaps to PDT (Pacific Daylight time) timezone.

```
var SCRIPT_START_TIME = new Date();
var jdbcDate = Jdbc.newTimestamp(SCRIPT_START_TIME.getTime());
console.log('start script: '+jdbcDate.getTime()); //start script: 1617369069432 - OK
...
var dbConnection = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://myserver.com:3306/mydatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8', {'user': dbUser, 'password': dbPass, 'useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift': true} );
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
...
var statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO `table` (product_id, last_search) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_search=?');
...
console.log('JDBC TimeStamp: '+ jdbcDate.getTime()); //JDBC TimeStamp: 1617369069432 - OK
statement.setTimestamp(2, jdbcDate);
statement.addBatch();
...
statement.executeBatch();
```

During the script runtime all timestamps are correct, represent actual time, but finally in MySQL a different timestamp is stored. If I query stored timestamp in SQL with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('last_search')` I get this: `1617336669`. It is a 9 hours earlier timestamp. At the moment the diff between PDT and my timezone is 9 hours. So not simple the "rendered" time string is changed, but the timestamp itself. During the JDBC connection the time of running shifts back in time 9 hours.

My scripts timezone is set correctly: `"timeZone": "Europe/Budapest",`

I found a more or less [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724946/date-returned-with-jdbc-is-in-pdt-timezone) here, but suggested `useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift` options didn't change anything.

Do you have any idea what cause this time shift during JDBC connection?

Comment: Try explicitly setting the timezone on your connection, eg using ` connectionTimeZone`, see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-datetime-types-processing.html

Comment: To add to @MarkRotteveel's point, try using this form of  [`setTimestamp(parameterIndex, x, timeZone)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement#settimestampparameterindex,-x,-timezone)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't mention because in Apps Script this parameter is not suppoerted. If I set I get `Error: Exception: The following connection properties are unsupported: connectionTimeZone.` error. :( Only few [parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl,-info) are supported.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot, Your suggestion looked to me promising, but despite timezone setting in .setTimestamp() still PDT timestamp is saved into database. :/

Comment: I have no clue about Google Apps Script, but is it possible to create and use a `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead?

Comment: What is the value of SCRIPT_START_TIME after you define it? Is this a standalone apps script project or is it bound to a file?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo SCRIPT_START_TIME returns with actual timestamp. It is a standalon script.

Comment: Can you verify that the returned timestamp is correct at the moment of logging?

Comment: As a workaround I replaced timestamp var with NOW() in SQL queries. :) It solves the problem, but does not reveal why JDBC shifts timestamps.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, I can verify that. I did lot of tests.